# Правильный запуск крона на Vesta

Tags: codeigniter, cron, vesta

Приветствую. Достался сайт на codeigniter. Файл Cron.php находится в папке site.com\application\controllers\Cron.php
Как правильно создать запрос, чтобы запустить крон. Панель Vesta.

Answer (score 0):

Добро пожаловать!

`php5 /home/юзер_весты/web/сайт_юзера/public_shtml/index.php cron функция_в_контроллере_Крон`

То есть, если нужно вызвать метод `removeUsersWithStatus($status)` с параметром `$status=123` из контроллере `Cron` для сайта `my-site.com` пользователя весты `VestaUserName` и при этом сайт `my-site.com` использует https (то есть лежит в папке public_shtml, а не просто public_html), ОС использует `php5` для вызова скриптов, то строка будет выглядеть как

`php5 /home/VestaUserName/web/my-site.com/public_shtml/index.php cron removeUsersWithStatus 123`